# XSLT expression ..IF NULL or EMPTY return all rows

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, filter, expression

I have this XPath expression which works to filter rows with a Contains wildcard string

But I would like it to return **ALL** rows initially, when search is null or empty. And I need to do it in line if at all possible.

```
[contains(translate(concat(' ',@Title,' '),$upper,$lower),$search)]
```

Note that if I pass a " " to $search all rows are returned. But I don't user to have to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
absoluteExpressionSelectingAllElements
    [not(absoluteExpressionSelectingAllElements
             [contains(translate(concat(' ',@Title,' '),$upper,$lower),$search)])
    ]

|

  absoluteExpressionSelectingAllElements
             [contains(translate(concat(' ',@Title,' '),$upper,$lower),$search)]
```

This expression is the union  ( `|` ) of two subexpressions one of which selects nothing, and the other selects either the result of the search, if non-empty, or all the elements.

**More generally, to get all nodes selected by `expr1` when a condition `cond` is `true()` and to get all nodes selected by `expr2`, when `cond` is `false()`, do** :

```
expr1[cond] | expr2[not(cond)]
```